# C# Unload Assembly in AppDomain without using raw byte arrays

Tags: c#, reflection, appdomain

I would like to unload a custom AppDomain and afterwards delete an assembly (from harddisk) which was loaded inside this AppDomain. I found a lot of resources suggesting to load the assembly via Assembly.Load(byte[]). Doing this makes it possible to delete the file, however, my code does not use this loaded assembly.

Basically I have two assemblies: A.dll and B.dll

A.dll references B.dll and wants to call into B.dll.

In my custom AppDomain I load both A.dll and B.dll via Assembly.LoadFrom. Then I invoke a method in A and it automatically calls into the loaded B.

The difficulty is that in the global AppDomain both A and B are already loaded, however, the version of B.dll loaded in the global AppDomain is not the same as the one I wish to load in the custom AppDomain.

Using the Assembly.LoadFrom method makes A call the correct version of B

Using the Assembly.Load(byte[]) method makes A call the version of B which is in the global AppDomain.

What I want is that either: loading A.dll as byte[] and B references it correctly, or loading A.dll with Assembly.LoadFrom but being able to delete it after unloading the AppDomain.

Has anyone an idea of how to achieve this?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one approach is to create a new AppDomain and use "shadow copying" to load the assemblies in the new domain. You  then should then be able to delete the assembly.

See: 
[AppDomain shadow copying not working (original assemblies locked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480140/appdomain-shadow-copying-not-working-original-assemblies-locked)